# Validating Go Ethereum key signature with ecrecover

Tags: signature, golang, ecrecover

### Resolved

The basic process flow of what I'm writing goes as follows.

- Sign a message with a private key and create an Ethereum address from the private key (AKA the `vettingAddress`)
- Pass the signature constituents to the contract along with a special hashed version of the hashed message ([See #Cheking If Correct](https://medium.com/@angellopozo/ethereum-signing-and-validating-13a2d7cb0ee3))

I don't have any problem doing with natively with Go, see below:

**Signing With Golang :**

```
func sign(message string, ecdsaKey *ecdsa.PrivateKey) []byte {
    hash := crypto.Keccak256([]byte(message))
    signature, _ := crypto.Sign(hash, ecdsaKey)
}
```

The resulting signature is validated easily with the Golang Ethereum lib using the following golang code:

**Validating / Verifying with Golang :**

```
func validate(ecdsaPubBytes []byte, signature []byte, messageHash []byte) bool {
    return crypto.VerifySignature(ecdsaPubBytes, messageHash , signature[:64])
}
```

So far so good this work perfectly.

---

My problem is with validating / verifying with an Ethereum smart contract, I have the following code:

**My Golang Code:**

```
type Signature struct {
    Hash [32]byte
    R    [32]byte
    S    [32]byte
    V    uint8
}

func Sign(message string) Signature {
    hashRaw := crypto.Keccak256([]byte(message))
    signature, err := crypto.Sign(hashRaw, ecdsaKey)
    p.errorHandler.Handle(err, "Signature error")

    validationMsg := "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + strconv.Itoa(len(message)) + message
    println(validationMsg)
    validationHash := crypto.Keccak256([]byte(validationMsg))

    return Signature{
        p.bytes32(validationHash),
        p.bytes32(signature[:32]),
        p.bytes32(signature[32:64]),
        uint8(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(signature[:65]))+27, // Yes add 27, weird Ethereum quirk
    }
}
```

*Passing to the network*

```
contract, _ := Signature(common.HexToAddress("..."), etherClient)
println(contract.VerifySig(callOpts, sig.Hash, sig.R, sig.S, sig.V, vettingAddress))
```

**My Solidity contract:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

library Signature {

    function verify(bytes32 hash, bytes32 r, bytes32 s,  uint8 v, address vettingAddress) internal pure returns(bool)
    {
        return ecrecover(hash, v, r, s) == vettingAddress;
    }
}
```

The contract is always returning false. There are very few resources for handling `ecrecover`, I've [read this article](https://medium.com/@angellopozo/ethereum-signing-and-validating-13a2d7cb0ee3)), but I don't see what I'm doing incorrectly.

---

### EDIT

I've solved this issue. The problem was related to how I parse the 65th byte of the signature. Below was incorrect for a number of reasons:

**Parse the Int correctly**

```
uint8(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(signature[:65]))+27, // Yes add 27, weird Ethereum quirk
```

Should look like:

```
uint8(int(signature[65])) + 27, // Yes add 27, weird Ethereum quirk
```

**Don't need a special hash**

Also the validation hash was not needed.

```
p.bytes32(validationHash),
```

Should be:

```
p.bytes32(hashRaw),
```

So all in all the new signature method looked like this:

```
type Signature struct {
    Raw   []byte
    Hash  [32]byte
    R     [32]byte
    S     [32]byte
    V     uint8
}

func Sign(message string) Signature {
    hashRaw := crypto.Keccak256([]byte(message))
    signature, err := crypto.Sign(hashRaw, p.ecdsa)
    p.errorHandler.Handle(err, "Signature error")

    return Signature{
        signature,
        p.bytes32(hashRaw),
        p.bytes32(signature[:32]),
        p.bytes32(signature[32:64]),
        uint8(int(signature[65])) + 27, // Yes add 27, weird Ethereum quirk
    }
}
```

Comment: NOTE: I post this as a question because I do not have enough reputation to comment. Hi Samuel Hawksby-Robinson, Thanks for your question and answer. You left out certain details of your example which makes it more difficult to reproduce: - How do you generate the keys for the right curve? - What is the variable 'p' that you are using? (For instance: p.bytes32 and p.ecdsa methods) - How do you create vettingAddress exactly? Would you be able to include this information? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please, correct for 64 index instead of 65

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this issue. The problem was related to how I parse the 65th byte of the signature. Below was incorrect for a number of reasons:

**Parse the Int correctly**

```
uint8(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(signature[:65]))+27, // Yes add 27, weird Ethereum quirk
```

Should look like:

```
uint8(int(signature[65])) + 27, // Yes add 27, weird Ethereum quirk
```

**Don't need a special hash**

Also the validation hash was not needed.

```
p.bytes32(validationHash),
```

Should be:

```
p.bytes32(hashRaw),
```

So all in all the new signature method looked like this:

```
type Signature struct {
    Raw   []byte
    Hash  [32]byte
    R     [32]byte
    S     [32]byte
    V     uint8
}

func Sign(message string) Signature {
    hashRaw := crypto.Keccak256([]byte(message))
    signature, err := crypto.Sign(hashRaw, p.ecdsa)
    p.errorHandler.Handle(err, "Signature error")

    return Signature{
        signature,
        p.bytes32(hashRaw),
        p.bytes32(signature[:32]),
        p.bytes32(signature[32:64]),
        uint8(int(signature[65])) + 27, // Yes add 27, weird Ethereum quirk
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be 64 index, not 65 
uint8(int(signature[64])) + 27

Answer (score 1):

I know that there is a library https://github.com/storyicon/sigverify that encapsulates the function of verifying Ethereum signatures in golang, including EIP712 and ERC1271.

Answer (score 0):

```
privatekeyPointer, err := crypto.HexToECDSA(privatekey)
message := "tokenXYZ,amount=10,price=1.23"
prefix := "\x19Ethereum Signed Message\n"
preSigned := prefix + strconv.Itoa(len(message)) + message
hashedMesg := crypto.Keccak256Hash([]byte(preSigned))
signatureBytes, err := crypto.Sign(hashedMesg.Bytes(), privatekeyPointer)

r := signatureBytes[:32]
s := signatureBytes[32:64]
v := uint8(int(signatureBytes[64])) + 27
```

reference: https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto#Sign